# Pros and cons of jQuery form validation plugins?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Which jQuery form plugin do you use, and would you recommend it?

Which other ones did you consider, and why did you ultimately not choose them?

There are quite a few, and we would love the broader SO community perspective before choosing one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751780/best-javascript-solution-for-client-side-form-validation-and-interaction) for an exhaustive discussion of the topic.